# Decoding AES with Base64 cyphertext and key

Tags: encryption, aes, block-cipher

I have a supposed AES cyphertext and key. 
They are both encoded in Base64 as they have trailing `=` for padding.

The key decodes down into 16 characters, so I am assuming its AES128.

I have tried to use the key and cyphertext to decode the message using 
the website “aesencryption.net” and OpenSSL with the following command:

```
openssl enc -d -aes-128-ecb -base64 -in cypherText.txt -out /dev/stdout -pass pass:key
```

The online decoder gives me unreadable text, and OpenSSL produces a bad magic number. I have also tried a few of the other supported AES modes in OpenSSL with no luck.

Am I missing a crucial step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is AES. The ciphertext decrypts to

```
user: part4, password: 97531
{{{
```

PS: after some experiments I was able to decrypt it using the OpenSSL command line:

```
openssl enc -d -aes-128-ecb -in cipher.txt -out plain.txt -nopad -nosalt -K 10EABCFF45E05EBB7AF9A228DD31F216 -iv 0 -base64
```

I converted the key from base64 to hex first.

Comment: Ok so it is AES. Can you point me where I went wrong with my decryption?

Comment: @bts37 - I edited the answer; looks like it is not possible to use the key in base64 encoding in openssl command line.

Comment: @kludg I followed the whole process, and I just get `warning: iv not used by this cipher` and empty plain.txt